# Can only read csv file with import gtk - Python - DictReader

Tags: python, csv, gtk, codec

Today I found a script which helped my to do the most work for changing my gtk2 scripts to gtk3: https://git.gnome.org//browse/pygobject/tree/pygi-convert.sh

But also a script which never used Gtk stopped working. Only because the "import gtk" was no longer in the script.

I tried now a few things to get it working without "import gtk", but could not get it running.

**Why is gtk changing my encoding?**

It is a **csv-file** downloaded from **ebay germany encoded in 'iso-8859-15' / 'latin'**.

I don't understand why this code is **only working with gtk import**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import gtk
import csv
import codecs
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(codecs.open(CSV_FILE, "r", encoding='iso-8859-15'), delimiter=';')
for row in csv_reader:
    pass
```

**Without "import gtk"**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_csv_ebaysales.py", line 9, in <module>
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 107, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

**Main Problem** is, that I want use use the DictReader and when I use without "import gtk" I have to use the keys in this way:

```
print row["Name des Käufers".decode("utf8").encode("latin")]
```

If I "import gtk" i can use this way:

```
print row["Name des Käufers"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I get it working was to **convert the csv file first to utf8**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

CSV_FILE = "EBAY_CSV/ebaycsvfile.csv"
CSV_FILE_UTF8 = "/tmp/utf8_ebay_csvfile.csv"

import csv
import codecs
with open(CSV_FILE) as infile:
    with codecs.open(CSV_FILE_UTF8, "wb", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
        inlines = [inline.decode("latin") for inline in infile.readlines()]
        outfile.writelines(inlines)

csv_reader = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_FILE_UTF8), delimiter=';')
for row in csv_reader:
    print row["Name des Käufers"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be `latin-1` encoded characters in your file. Changing `encoding='iso-8859-15'` to `encoding='latin-1'` should solve this.

Comment: I have tried this already, if I change this I get: 
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 45: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Sorry, this is indeed not `utf-8`. Try `latin-1` instead.

Comment: Then I get again: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128). - But I can open without set an encoding or only use open instead if codecs.open.